# Leafletjs add Global Radar To Map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, wms

I am using leaflet-radar from this source https://github.com/rwev/leaflet-radar
It works great for American radar data, and I modified the code to take an array of WMS urls so I can pull more than just American radar data.

I am having trouble locating sources for WMS in other countries, or ideally global data. Is there an easier way to get leaflet radar data globally or at least in other North American countries?
`NEXRAD_URL: ['https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0q.cgi'], NEXRAD_LAYER: ['nexrad-n0q-900913'],`
This is what I have for pulling American radar data so far.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.